# Why does tblr not work with commands that contain &?

Tags: tabularray

I am using a command that contains more than one cell (containing an `&` to separate them).

It worked with `tabular` it does not work with `tbrl` though. Why?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\newcommand{\ab}{a & b}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tblr}{c|l}
        \ab \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

The error message is `misplaced alignment tab character &`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the argument `expand` in the table specification:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\newcommand{\ab}{a & b}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tblr}[expand=\ab]{c|l}
        \ab \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

More information on this can be found [in the docs p. 30](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray), the reasoning is:

> In contrast to traditional tabular environment, tabularray
> environments need to see every & and \ when splitting the table body
> with l3regex. And you can not put cell text inside any table command
> defined with `\NewTableCommand`. But you could use outer key `expand` to
> make tabularray expand every occurrence of a specified macro once
> before splitting the table body. Note that you can not expand a
> command defined with `\NewDocumentCommand`