# Insert n empty rows using tblr

Tags: expl3, tabularray

I just wanted to insert n empty rows using tlbr like this:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{expl3}


\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \makerows \prg_replicate:nn 
\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

With tabular: 

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
a & b & c & d \\\hline
\makerows{5}{ & & &  \\\hline} 
\end{tabular}

With tblr:

\begin{tblr}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
a & b & c & d \\\hline
%\makerows{5}{ & & &  \\\hline} 

%% Gives
% ! Misplaced alignment tab character &.
% <argument>  &
%               & & \\\hline 

\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

Using `tabular` it works, using `tblr` it doesn't . How can I fix this?

Comment: See my answer to a question yesterday concerning a similar issue with `tblr`, `tblr` needs to see the `&` in advance, I tried using `expand=\makerows` in your question but it still doesn't work, hopefully someone else can help!: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/691258/273733

Comment: @JamesT: In the meantime I found some variations which work, see my answer below. But I don't really understand why some work and others don't.

Comment: The `lua` version is interesting how that works, will try that in the future, nice workaround

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{functional}

\IgnoreSpacesOn
\prgNewFunction \makerows {m} {
\intReplicate {#1} {{} &   &   &  \\\hline }
}
\IgnoreSpacesOff

\begin{document}

With tabular: 

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
a & b & c & d \\\hline
\makerows{5}
\end{tabular}

With tblr:

\begin{tblr}[evaluate=\makerows]{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
a & b & c & d \\\hline
\makerows{5}
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

Adapted from the example of the tabularray manual on page 46. However I am not quite sure why I need the empty `{}` in the definition of my empty row.

Nevertheless I want to understand why the initial latex3 approach didn't work. The problem seems to be related to the replicate function.

**Edit**

Using `lualatex` seems to work with the expand-key as mentioned by @JamesT in the comment above:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}


\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
function makerows(n)
for i = 1, n
do
  tex.sprint("& & & \\\\\\hline")
end
end

\end{luacode}
  
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}[expand=\directlua]{c|c|c|c}
a & b & c & d \\\hline
\directlua{makerows(10)}
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

**Edit 2**

I also tried `pythontex` which does **not** work even with the expand key:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[gobble=auto]{pythontex}

\begin{pycode}
def makerows(n):
    for i in range(0,n):
        print(r"& & & \\\hline")
\end{pycode}
  
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}[expand=\pyc]{c|c|c|c}
a & b & c & d \\\hline
\pyc{makerows(3)}
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

I guess it doesn't work, because

> Printed content is saved in a file and then included via
> \InputIfFileExists. But \InputIfFileExists is not expandable

as described [here](https://github.com/gpoore/pythontex/issues/25#issuecomment-26922469).